# Writing to a struct to a text file using StreamWriter

Tags: c#, streamwriter

Below is a function which should ask the user the questions and whatever the user enters it should be saved to the text file.

It is a struct which should accept 1 `int`, 4 `strings` and a `DateTime`. This is what my function looks like so far but its obviously not working. The console is displaying the questions but isn't saving to the text file.

```
static void AddNew(CustomerStruct[] _NewCustomer)
{
    Console.Clear();

    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"..\..\..\Files\Customer.txt", true))
    {
        Console.Write("\n\n Enter Customer Number: ");
        sw.WriteLine(_NewCustomer[RecCount].CustomerNo);

        Console.Write("\n\n Enter Customer Surname: ");
        sw.WriteLine(_NewCustomer[RecCount].Surname);

        Console.Write("\n\n Enter Customer Forname: ");
        sw.WriteLine(_NewCustomer[RecCount].Forename);

        Console.Write("\n\n Enter Customer Street address: ");
        sw.WriteLine(_NewCustomer[RecCount].Street);

        Console.Write("\n\n Enter Customer Town: ");
        sw.WriteLine(_NewCustomer[RecCount].Town);

        Console.Write("\n\n Enter Customer DOB: ");
        sw.WriteLine(_NewCustomer[RecCount].DOB);

        RecCount++;
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Mayhaps you'd like to *read* that data from the console before writing it to the file?

Comment: Using streamreader? I tried to do that at one stage I had different ways of attempting to do it but none of them worked.

Comment: What do you have in `_NewCustomer`? Is it empty? What is `RecCount'?

Comment: I think(lol) _NewCustomer is pointing to the address of an structure of an array that was created in abother part of the progrm. I want RecCount to count to the end of stream and add it to the next element in the array therefore not overwritting anything.. RecCount++ shouldn't be in there

Comment: So, you want to have the data you read from Console in the file and also in the struct, right?

Comment: I added Console.Readline(); below each question but before the sw.writeline... then after running the program and filling in the new customer details i get this at the end of the text file :

0




01/01/0001 00:00:00

- Noting significant but more than i was getting before.

Comment: No just in the file would be fine

Comment: OK. Edited my answer. Now, do you need to read some data (customer #, name, etc.) multiple times? Is that what you tried to accomplish with `RecCount`?

Comment: I just included reccount because I wanted the writeline to write to an element with nothing in it therefore not overwriting. at the minute the array size is 100 there are 10 entries so I would want the write line to write to the 11 entry or would this happen automatically anyway?

Comment: Not automatically, you will need a loop for that. Can you please state your final goal for this? You want to read data from console N times and write this data to a file?

Comment: No, sorry. I want to read data from the console. 
What is the new customers number? : 1010 
What is the new customers forename? : Ben
etc, etc...

Now this info i want read and written to a text file which already contains other customers info...

I only want to read the data for one instance. After that data is saved I the user of the program may want to and enter another new customers info 2 hours later, if you get my drift..

Comment: OK. Then the code snippet in my answer will work for you. Data in the file will not be overridden because you `new StreamWriter(pathToYourFile , true)`. This last `true` argument tells `StreamWriter` to append data to file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like shorcuts

```
static void AddNew(CustomerStruct[] _NewCustomer)
{
Console.Clear();

using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"..\..\..\Files\Customer.txt", true))
{
    Console.Write("\n\n Enter Customer Number: ");
    sw.WriteLine(_NewCustomer[RecCount].CustomerNo=Console.ReadLine());

    Console.Write("\n\n Enter Customer Surname: ");
    sw.WriteLine(_NewCustomer[RecCount].Surname=Console.ReadLine());

    Console.Write("\n\n Enter Customer Forname: ");
    sw.WriteLine(_NewCustomer[RecCount].Forename=Console.ReadLine());

    Console.Write("\n\n Enter Customer Street address: ");
    sw.WriteLine(_NewCustomer[RecCount].Street=Console.ReadLine());

    Console.Write("\n\n Enter Customer Town: ");
    sw.WriteLine(_NewCustomer[RecCount].Town=Console.ReadLine());

    Console.Write("\n\n Enter Customer DOB: ");
    sw.WriteLine(_NewCustomer[RecCount].DOB=Console.ReadLine());

    RecCount++;
}

Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: (1) Not sure what `RecCount++;` does (not sure what it does in the question either); (2) `Console.ReadLine()` returns a `string`. So assignment may fail depending on the `CustomerStruct` fields types.

Comment: (1)for **RecCount++** its in his code (maybe he is incrementing a global variable);

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in your comment, you just need data from Console in the file. So, this is an answer to "**How do I read data from Console and put it in a file?**".

You want to read data from console and then write it to stream:

```
public static void ReadNewCustomerFromConsole()
{
    var pathToYourFile = @"..\..\..\Files\Customer.txt";

    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(pathToYourFile , true))
    {
        Console.Clear();

        // Write a message in Console
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Customer Number: ");

        // Read user input from Console
        var customerNumber = Console.ReadLine();

        // Write user input to file
        writer.WriteLine(customerNumber);

        // Now read Customer Surname
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Customer Surname:");
        var customerSurname = Console.ReadLine();
        writer.WriteLine(customerSurname);

        // And so on for the other data you need ...
    }
}
```

Note that I use `Console.WriteLine()` instead of including `\n`.

Also, I would suggest to rename your method to something like `ReadNewCustomerFromConsole()` and don't pass an array of `struct` in it if you don't really want to fill it with the read information (and if you do, I would suggest using `class` instead of `struct`).

Comment: Its part of an assignment and we haven't been taught classes.

Comment: instead of `var customerNumber = Console.ReadLine();` it should be `var _NewCustomer[RecCount].CustomerNo=Console.ReadLine()` right?

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to achieve. 

If you want just to read information from console, write it to your file and forget about it, then a local variable (`customerNumber` that will be of type `string`) is the way to go. 

On the other hand, if you want to read the data, write it to your file and then use this data again somewhere else in the method (without reading it from the file), then you should keep track of what you read. I would suggest to do it with a `List<CustomerStruct>` thought.